# Firefox 5 gives all CSS when running getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript, firefox

Using firefox 5 when i run

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0], null);
```

I get the complete css file, instead of the styles applied onto the "img" tag.

I ran this on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Anyone knows of a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an older post, but for anyone landing here.

Basic idea: you need to call the `getPropertyValue()` method on the object returned by `window.getComputedStyle()`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zupa/jyyt9/

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) states you don't need to call `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle()` but `window.getComputedStyle`

**Note** that window.getComputedStyle() returns used values not computed values. (See previous link.)

Compatibility tables: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility), [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html)

Answer (score 1):

It should give you an object of type `ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration` that includes all styles that have been set. This includes all possible styles and not only those styles that have been manipulated by you in some way.

In order to get a specific rule, use for example:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0], null)['borderLeftColor'];
```

This gives the left border color without distinguishing how the value as specified / calculated.

To get a list of the available entries print the object to Firebug's console:

```
console.dir(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0], null));
```

Comment: What output is printed if you open up Firebug and run `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0], null).toString()` after your page has loaded? Make sure to enable “Show JavaScript Errors” in the Console tab first.

Comment: this is shown. "[object ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration]" and without toString this is the text in the object body {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0;
}
img {
    border: medium none;
}
h1 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 29px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#top_bg {
    background: url("../images/top_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
 and more

Comment: This tells us that Firefox did indeed return the object which it is supposed to return. Now, goto http://jsfiddle.net/SuQtT/ and check if the color is printed next to the image. You should see a textual representation of the red border color.

Which version of Firebug are you running? It should not display the CSS files' sources when you query the computed styles.

Comment: i added a console.log to the fiddle. see the object that is printed.

Comment: I've had a look on your `console.log` call and they object is printed as it should be. I want to add that clicking the object in Firebug's console results in Firebug showing its CSS panel. This does not provided any useful information but does not affect your original question since it just affects Firebug's display. Right-clicking the object in the console and choosing _Inspect in DOM tab_ shows the object nicely.
Do you see the textual representation of red? If yes, your Firebug displays the object confusingly and Firefox gives a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0], "");
```

Comment: even this returns the whole css